# What is the integral of this function over the interval [-1, 1]?

Tags: integration

$$
f(x)= 
  \begin{cases}
    0,                    & x=0 \\
    \dfrac{1}{\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{\vert x \vert} \right\rfloor }, 
                          & -1\le x\le 1 \text{ and } x\ne 0
  \end{cases}
$$

The domain of the above function $f(x)$ is $[-1, 1]$.

I understand that the function looks like a step function. Its value is $1$ in $(\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, and $\frac{1}{2}$ in $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}]$. In general, its value is $\frac{1}{n}$ in $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$ for $n\ge 1$.

I also understand that the function is also continuous at $x=0$ since for any given $\epsilon < 1$, there exists an $n\ge 1$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, and choose $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$, then we have a $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ proof of continuity. I am amazed to see this continuity result by the way.

What is the value of $\int^1_{-1} f(x)dx$? I find it hard to deal with infinite steps.

Comment: Can you find the value of $\int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} f(x)\,dx$ for a given positive integer $n$? Can you use that value to calculate $\int_{1/m}^1 f(x)\,dx$ for a given integer $m\ge2$? What does that tell you about $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: Tried that but still stuck somewhere. $\int^{1/n}_{1/(n+1)} f(x)dx = 1/n * (1/n - 1/(n+1))$. I am not aware any technique for example telescope to simplify the $\sum$ formula ahead. Pls advise.

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx = 2\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$. As you correctly noticed, $f(x) = \frac{1}{n}, x \in \left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}
\right]$, so $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \chi
_\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right](x)$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of a set $A$ ($\chi(x) = 1$ for $x\in A$ and 0 otherwise).
The main part of calculating $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ is to explain why one can swap integration and infinite summation:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \chi
_\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right](x) dx = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 \chi
_\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right](x) dx
$$
It can be proven via [bounded convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem) for sequence $f_m = f \cdot \chi_\left[\frac{1}{m+1}, 1\right], m \in \mathbb{N}$.
As $\int_0^1 \chi
_\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right](x) = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}
$$
It it's [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.
As $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$, second sum equals 1 as telescopic sum ($1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} - \dots$). So, $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1$ and hence $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = \frac{\pi^2}{3} - 2$.

Comment: The 'swap' part is beyond my knowledge. But I got your idea of using Basel problem's result.